# System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException Catching all errors

Tags: powershell

I am having issues with a try/catch block where the catch block for `System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException` is catching all errors regardless if they're of type `System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException` or not. The problem is when I move the try/catch block outside of the script into it's own for testing, the try/catch works as intended.

The try/catch is inside a for/each so they only thing I can think of is that the loop is somehow tripping up the try/catch block? The one error it loves catching is `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException`.

<s>Below is the test script I made that works as intended, but placed within the foreach doesn't:</s>

I actually got the error to manifest with this:

```
foreach($x in Get-ChildItem){
    Get-Acl "C:\fake"
    try {
        $Acl = Get-Acl
        Set-Acl LiteralPath "C:\temp" $Acl -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Access Rule Added" -ForegroundColor Cyan            
    }            
    catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {                
        Write-Host "Insufficient Priviliege. Owner: $($Acl.Owner) ($_)" -ForegroundColor Red    

    }
    catch [System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException] {
        Write-Host "Invalid Prinicpal! ($_)" -ForegroundColor Red
        $abort = Read-Host -Prompt "Abort? (Y)"
        if($abort -ieq "Y"){ Exit }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "ALL: $_" -ForegroundColor Red    
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `.InnerException` to see if it is in fact an `IdentityNotMapped` exception?

Comment: `.InnerException` is empty for both `System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException` errors and `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException` errors. I don't understand why it's catching the latter.

Comment: Hm, what about just checking `.GetType()` on the exception? Also please post your code (or a [mcve]).

Comment: That's how I got the types to set my catch blocks. The only solution I've found so far is create a redundant catch block specifically for `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException` errors. :\

Comment: Is it in a `foreach` statement or in a `ForEach-Object` scriptblock?

Comment: It is in a foreach statement.

Comment: Could you show how you're invoking it?

Comment: I've updated the question with a codeblock that creates the error.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer to my question (as I don't fully understand why it was happening and as such it might snag on something else) but adding `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the `Get-Acl` command that was throwing the first error helps prevent the errant catching:

```
foreach($x in Get-ChildItem){
    Get-Acl "C:\fake" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    try {
        $Acl = Get-Acl
        Set-Acl LiteralPath "C:\temp" $Acl -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Access Rule Added" -ForegroundColor Cyan            
    }            
    catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {                
        Write-Host "Insufficient Priviliege. Owner: $($Acl.Owner) ($_)" -ForegroundColor Red    

    }
    catch [System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException] {
        Write-Host "Invalid Prinicpal! ($_)" -ForegroundColor Red
        $abort = Read-Host -Prompt "Abort? (Y)"
        if($abort -ieq "Y"){ Exit }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "ALL: $_" -ForegroundColor Red    
    }
}
```

Though it's strange how `$_` doesn't display the actual error but just `AclObject` in this instance.